# Why coroutineScope block UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have such code.
If I run this code in debug mode with breakpoints,
then ComposableLayout will be first,
then code stops at Column(),
after breakpoint will stops in function setMessage,
but screen view shows only bottomBar view, no Column view.
Why?

Why all Column view doesn't show before setMessage function?

```
setContent {
 lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
    setMessage(viewModel = viewModel)
 }
 ComposableLayout(
      viewModel = viewModel
 )
}

suspend fun setMessage(viewModel: viewModel) = coroutineScope {
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                }
            }
}

@Composable
fun ComposableLayout() {

Scaffold() { innerPadding ->
bottomBar = {}
Column()
}
```

In ComponentActivity by setcontent I want to run a function which will get data and set it to ViewModel but I need to show @Composable view which asynchronously will fill the fields.

Comment: In Compose, the recomposition and rendering of composables happen asynchronously. When you call setMessage(viewModel), which is a suspending function, and then launch another coroutine within it, Compose continues executing the composition logic and rendering the UI. It doesn't wait for the suspension points to complete before rendering.

Comment: I have done all correct? You mean if I have a lot of data to load in setMessage it will not lag the view screen?

Comment: My main idea is to show view, and then load data if it was intercepts to MutableStateFlow in ViewModel which was triggered by setMessage

Comment: yeah If your main concern is to ensure that the UI remains responsive while data is being loaded in setMessage, using coroutines and MutableStateFlow is a suitable approach. By launching the data loading operation in a background thread using Dispatchers.Default or another appropriate dispatcher, you prevent blocking the main UI thread and keep the UI responsive.

Comment: but if I have call int this Dispatchers.Default viewModelScope and in it emitting value, but Ui not responding on it, and wait then viewModelScope end

Comment: but why I could see the bottomBar and other screen are blank. Why I can't see empty fields? And fill it asynchronously?

Comment: If you want to simulate a large message, you can add `delay(5000)` before  `setMessage` and you'll see what happens